# Ubuntu 11.04 deletes files immediately (Trash is empty)

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

My Ubuntu 11.04 deletes files immediately – the trash can is empty. I delete files using right-click "Move to trash" or <kbd>Del</kbd> (not <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Open file manager. Places/Computer

Click edit/Preferences/Behavior

check off "Ask before emptying trash or deleting files." (if it is not checked)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. I don't know how to solve the problem, but I figured a way around it:

Under your user-profile's directory, navigate to

> .local/share/Trash/files

This is where your trash is actually located.

I don't think your files are automatically getting deleted rather than going to the trash. They are in fact going into the trash; apparently it's some **bug that makes it seem as if the trash is empty** and I'm pretty sure it doesn't even open when you attempt to open it.